# how to add jcombobox to jtable column in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable, jcombobox

[image]

I want to add jcombobox to jtable please someone explain me how could i do that in netbeans

Comment: Don't use NetBeans. Spend time learning how to write Java code yourself. Otherwise if you move to a different IDE then you will need to learn another IDE and the generated code may not be accepted by the other IDE.

Comment: Why did you post an image from [the tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox) and not take the time to try something

Comment: i have tried but i can't understand how to use that tutorial in netbeans

Answer (score 9):

Add a `JComboBox` by dragging and dropping outside the frame or panel.So that it will be added to `OtherComponents` in the Navigator View

[image]

Add whatever contents you want to add by double clicking the combobox from Navaigator View

Then rightclick on `JTable` and click TableContents

[image]

In the Dialog select `Columns` Tab(1) and select the column(2) you want to add the combobox to.

Then Click on the button near to the Editor[Ref screenshot (3)]

Then in the editor dialog Choose `Custom Code` from the dropdown(4)

Then put the following(5)

```
new DefaultCellEditor(jComboBox1)//jComboBox1 is the variable name of combobox
```

[image]

Then Click ok and close and make sure you import `import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;` or do a `Ctrl+Shift+I` to add the necessary imports

After that If you run and click on column 2 you'll get this output

[image]

Comment: This was very helpful.

Comment: This worked for me and I will Recommend it to all people who have the same problem